# Non authorized actions with Policy gradient algorithm

Tags: reinforcement-learning, policy-gradient

I am using Reinforce algorithm to learn the optimal policy in  problem  where the action space is dynamic. It depends on the state, in each state, the agent is allowed  to choose among a subset of the general action space.
At each state, the policy network outputs a probability distribution over the actions, however some actions are not allowed and get a chance to be sampled.
What I tried is to modify the output of the policy network and assign a zero probability to the non authorized actions. I want to  know if there is another approach  to solve this issue without hard-coding the probabilities because this lead to a sub-optimal behavior.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/2980/how-to-handle-invalid-moves-in-reinforcement-learning and https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/11142/how-to-back-propagate-illegal-actions-for-policy-gradient-learning

Comment: Thnaks @Apprentice for your reply